# Graphite importing historical data only for 1 day

Tags: linux, monitoring, graphite, whisper, graphite-carbon

I'm trying to import historical data for 60 day per hour, but data succsessfully importing only for last 24 hours, configuration bellow:

Storage schema in Graphite `/etc/carbon/storage-schemas.conf`

```
[default]
pattern = .*
retentions = 5m:15d,15m:1y,1h:10y,1d:100y
```

Storage aggregation `/etc/carbon/storage-aggregation.conf`

```
[all_sum]
pattern = .*
xFilesFactor = 0.0
aggregationMethod = sum
```

Restarting carbon-cache and removing old whisper data is not solving problem.
I checked .wsp files with `wisper-info.py`:

```
# whisper-info /var/lib/graphite/whisper/ran/3g/newerlang.wsp 
maxRetention: 3153600000
xFilesFactor: 0.0
aggregationMethod: sum
fileSize: 1961584

Archive 0
retention: 1296000
secondsPerPoint: 300
points: 4320
size: 51840
offset: 64

Archive 1
retention: 31536000
secondsPerPoint: 900
points: 35040
size: 420480
offset: 51904

Archive 2
retention: 315360000
secondsPerPoint: 3600
points: 87600
size: 1051200
offset: 472384

Archive 3
retention: 3153600000
secondsPerPoint: 86400
points: 36500
size: 438000
offset: 1523584
```

Any idea if I need to set this up in another file or am I missing something?

Comment: did yu manage to fix this? do you have any other sections on your `/etc/carbon/storage-schemas.conf`  besides the `[default]`?